# How to map all virtual addresses (VAs) in a PE image to Relative VAs

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, virtual-address-space, relocation

I want to read an image of a module (loaded in the memory of a process), into a buffer, using the Win32 C++ API. After reading I want to change all VAs in from the buffer, into RVAs.

I've found the [`ImageRvaToVa`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680218%28VS.85%29.aspx) function on MSDN, however, I would need the reverse mapping, i.e. `ImageVaToRva` and I would need to apply it for all VAs inside of the given image. However, I couldn't find such a function or anything similar to it. Does such a function exist in Win32?

One way to do what I want would be to parse the `.reloc` section of the image. However, I didn't find any straightforward way to do this. Are there any Win32 API functions that can easily parse the `.reloc` section?

Any other suggestions for approaches to solving this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: I want to check if any code loaded into process memory has changed. For this I need to ignore any relocations that occurred when the PE file was mapped.

Comment: why would it change? The code is marked read-only. It can only be modified by a user with sufficient privileges to change memory permissions in other processes. And users who can do that can also cheat whatever other mechanisms you come up with to check that nothing has been tampered with.

Comment: Sure you are totally right. My mistake, I actually want to compute a hash of the code of each loaded module and I can only verify the result if nothing inside the loaded image changes. Otherwise the result is different.

Comment: Why not just hash the executable file?

Comment: I can hash the file, but I have to check if the hash of an image loaded in process memory matches the hash of the file. The loaded image and the original file don't necessarily need to have the same name and path.